# Unable to click item inside custom app bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a custom app bar inside my app but after the ios 15 update i can't click anything inside it. I tried almost everything and nothing works. I don't know why, but on ios 15 my app is not usable at all due to changes that apple make.

Please help me because i need to update my app as soon as possible otherwise i will loose all of my users

(I'm beginner on ios development)

**My Custom App bar view:**

```
struct appBar: View {
    
    @Binding var index: Int
    @State var showGoalTipsScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            
            HStack {
                
                Text("My Goals")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                Button(action: {
                    showGoalTipsScreen = true
                }) {
                    
                    Text("Add New Goal")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Image("addIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.index = 0
                }, label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Active")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(self.index == 0 ? .bold : .none)
                        
                        Capsule().fill(self.index == 0 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                            .frame(height: 4)
                        
                    }
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.index = 1
                }, label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Completed")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(self.index == 1 ? .bold : .none)
                        
                        Capsule().fill(self.index == 1 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                            .frame(height: 4)
                        
                    }
                })
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.index = 2
                }, label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Shared")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(self.index == 2  ? .bold : .none)
                        
                        Capsule().fill(self.index == 2 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                            .frame(height: 4)
                        
                    }
                })
                
                
                NavigationLink("", destination: GoalTipsView().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $showGoalTipsScreen)
                                
                
            }.padding(.bottom, 10)
            
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, (UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)! + 10)
        .background(RoundedCorners(tl: 0, tr: 0, bl: 13, br: 13).fill(Color.blue))
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Does your state variable `showGoalTipsScreen` get changed to `true` on tap?